# android app crashes after getting killed by task manager

Tags: android

my problem: if my app is going to be destroyed by a task manager on the phone, after restart the app can't access the sqlite database. it is possible to access it be openOrCreateDatabase but it crashes if I perform some query on the db. the query works if I don't destroy it by task manager! does smbdy has a hint?

Comment: Can you give some stack trace of the error ?

Comment: I have found out something. I got a simple context object (which is an activity) and this is beeing deallocated. but I have defined:android: launchMode="singleInstance" so why is this possible that the activity gets null=???????